# How can I asynchronously edit/update a static mysql result with a text box?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, asynchronous

I am pulling in values from MySQL into a php page like so:

```
$query = 'SELECT cinfo.`client_id`, cinfo.`client_first_name`, cinfo.`client_last_name` ';
$query.= 'FROM `client_information` AS cinfo ';
$query.= 'ORDER BY cinfo.`client_id` ';
```

These are being displayed within a table that has a loop for each row:

```
$result = mysql_unbuffered_query( $query );
echo "<table border='1'>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>Client ID</th>";
    echo "<th>Client First Name</th>";
    echo "<th>Client Last Name</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{   
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['client_id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['client_first_name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['client_last_name'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

I have also set up an update/delete script in a separate file, assuming that on 'update' or 'delete' variables storing the info will be passed to that file and run an update to the client's information based on the ID.

My lack of knowledge is the asynchronous aspect of submission, and I am having trouble incorporating javascript/jquery into the results to edit and update the values stored within the database without a page refresh.  Does anyone have an idea on how to best accomplish this?

Essentially I'd like the page to act as shown below:

Info as pulled from MySQL:
[image: Info as pulled from MySQL]

After the user clicks "Edit":
[image: Editing information]

Information after update:
[image: Updated information with notification]

Comment: have you ever heard of AJAX?

Comment: Yes, however I am not as familiar with it as I would like to be.  I just need a step in the right direction I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

[AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) will do the trick for you.

Check these out: [jQuery POST](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) and [jQuery Ajax POST examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example).

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look at your links and see if I can incorporate the logic!  If anyone else has any information for me, I would greatly appreciate it!  Thank you!